# Change in memory upload file size in grails

Tags: grails, multipartform-data

I'd like to increase file size, which stays in memory when uploading it to grails app (meaning its not written to hdd). I've read some suggestions to define multipartResolver bean and set the maxInMemorySize property:

```
multipartResolver(org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver){ 
    maxInMemorySize=10240  
}
```

However I've found out that grails already defines this bean, so with my definition I would overwrite all the other settings defined by grails. Is this really a good approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you're probably removing some configuration that Grails does, and even if you copy the entire original bean definition and make your one change, the Grails definition could change in the future and you would prevent that too.

In this case it looks like you can change this property at any time; the setter in the Spring bean sets the value on a private instance of `DiskFileItemFactory`, and [looking at its source](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html) it appears that this is a safe change to make.

So I would add a dependency injection for the bean in BootStrap and make the change there, e.g.

```
class BootStrap {

   def multipartResolver

   def init = {
      multipartResolver.maxInMemorySize = 10240
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, would you favor setting the value in bootstrap over BeanPostProcessor ?

Comment: Absolutely. BeanPostProcessor (and similar types like BeanFactoryPostProcessor, etc.) are very powerful and give you access to lots of information during bean building, but are overkill for something like this.